# How can i solve the error: iostreams currently clash with eosio::datastream?

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.cdt, c++

I am trying to compile some code which compiled successfully with the old compiler `eosiocpp`, but with the new `eosio-cpp` gives me: `eosio.cdt/1.4.0/bin/../include/libcxx/iostream:13:2: error: "iostreams currently clash with eosio::datastream"`

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to remove `#include<iostream>`. Unfortunately, using .cdt 1.4, there are some issues with print and it is not possible to print a string variable right now.
See more details at the issue https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2984